# Markdown: lists are not well converted

Tags: list, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to create a list in Markdown. As I've read in some documentation, if I write this Markdown code:

```
My list
* first item
* second item
* third item

Not in the list
```

I would get as result the same as if I write this in HTML:

```html
<p>My list</p>
<li>
   <ul>first item</ul>
   <ul>second item</ul>
   <ul>third item</ul>
</li>
<p>Not in the list</p>
```

I use Atom as editor and its Markdown previewer and everything is OK, but when I use `pandoc` to convert my Markdown file as follows:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.odt
```

what I get is this:

```
My list * first item * second item * third item
Not in the list
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing empty line after `My list`. You can test this in the StackOverflow post preview.

Comment: Wow, that's a simple and stupid fail I've done... Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not make this an answer so the question can be closed

Comment: @AlexHarvey do you mean me?

Comment: No I meant @melpomene. The question shows up as unanswered that wastes everyone's time if people answer the questions here in comments.

Comment: If melpomene doesn't do it in some days (let him some time), you could do it, @AlexHarvey :)

Comment: @AlexHarvey I voted to close this question as off-topic. I don't see how it's programming related.

Comment: I don't see how it's not programming-related. There are ~5,000 questions in Stack Overflow tagged "markdown".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to your problem:

1. Add a blank line between the paragraph and the list (as @melpomene mentioned in a comment).

   ```
   My list

   * first item
   * second item
   * third item

   Not in the list
   ```
2. Leave out the blank line and tell Pandoc to use `commonmark` as the [input format](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--from) rather than the default, `markdown`.

   ```
   pandoc -f commonmark -o test.odt test.md
   ```

The "problem" is that the Atom editor uses a CommonMark parser and, by default, Pandoc uses an old-school Markdown parser which mostly follows [these rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) and the reference implementation (`markdown.pl`). In fact, the [Commonmark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#example-266) specifically acknowledges this difference:

> In CommonMark, a list can interrupt a paragraph. That is, no blank
>   line is needed to separate a paragraph from a following list:
>
> ```
> Foo
> - bar
> - baz
>
> <p>Foo</p>
> <ul>
> <li>bar</li>
> <li>baz</li>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> `Markdown.pl` does not allow this, through fear of triggering a list
>   via a numeral in a hard-wrapped line:
>
> ```
> The number of windows in my house is
> 14.  The number of doors is 6.
> ```

If you want common behavior among your tools, then you need to only use tools which follow the same behavior.